# A custom find function

Tags: function, vba, excel

I am trying to create a function which, after having search the entire active worksheet, will return the total number of cells that contain a certain string. A lot like how the "x cell(s) found" within Find and Replace works.

I have this so far:

```
Function FINDIST(stringToFind)
Dim counter As Integer: counter = 0
For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
If InStr (Cell, stringToFind) > 0
Then counter = counter + 1
End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Replace `Function FINDIST(stringToFind)` by `Function FINDIST(stringToFind) AS Long`.  Replace `Dim counter As Integer` by `Dim counter As Long`. Add `FINDDIST = counter` before `End Function`.  This will be very slow. `UsedRange` can easily be the entire worksheet.  Look up `Find` in VBA help where it shows how to find every occurrence of a string.  Don't forget to include `LookAt:=xlPart`.

Comment: Ok, you bring up an interesting topic. I did read the Find method documentation but I don't see it returning a boolean. I need a boolean for the IF.

Comment: Why do you need a boolean?  I assume it is the match count you want the function to return.  Just include `counter = counter + 1` within the `Find` loop and return the final value of `counter`.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction. Look at the answers + their comments to see exactly how *WE* fixed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way of doing this:

```
Function FINDIST(stringToFind) As Long
    FINDIST = Evaluate("SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(" & Chr(34) _
        & "*" & stringToFind & "*" & Chr(34) & "," _
            & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address & ",1),0))")
End Function
```

This searches for `stringToFind` in every cell in used range, and returns an array with a 1 if that string is found in a cell and error if it is not found. The error is casted to zero with the `IFERROR` part, and the `SUM` sums the resulting binary array.

This will count only once the occurrence of `stringToFind` within each cell, even if it occurs more than once, but looking at your code I assume that this is what you are looking for.

I hope it helps!

**UPDATE**

Out of curiosity, I did some testing to see how the two approaches compare (read from range directly vs using evaluate). Here is the code I used:

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long

Sub test()
Dim ticks As Long
Range("A1:AA100000").Value = "adlrkjgalbabyajglakrjg"

ticks = GetTickCount
FINDIST1 ("baby")
Debug.Print "Read from range: ", GetTickCount - ticks

ticks = GetTickCount
FINDIST ("baby")
Debug.Print "Evaluate: ", GetTickCount - ticks

End Sub

Function FINDIST(stringToFind) As Long
    FINDIST = Evaluate("SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(" & Chr(34) _
    & "*" & stringToFind & "*" & Chr(34) & "," _
      & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address & ",1),0))")
End Function


Function FINDIST1(stringToFind) As Long
Dim counter As Long: counter = 0
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set c = .Find(stringToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            counter = counter + 1
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

FINDIST1 = counter

End Function
```

**UPDATE 2**

Chris Nielsen made two very good points in the comments below:

- `ActiveSheet.Evaluate` is faster than `Application.Evaluate`. The link to the text by Charles Williams in the comment explains this behavior.
- Good old `Variant` array will perform better than any other method.

For completeness, I post the version of the `variant` array method that I tested:

```
Function FINDIST_looping(stringToFind) As Long
    Dim vContents, lRow As Long, lCol As Long, lCounter As Long

    vContents = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2
    For lRow = LBound(vContents, 1) To UBound(vContents, 1)
        For lCol = LBound(vContents, 2) To UBound(vContents, 2)
            lCounter = IIf(InStr(vContents(lRow, lCol), stringToFind), _ 
               lCounter + 1, lCounter)
        Next lCol
    Next lRow

FINDIST_looping = lCounter

End Function
```

Doug Glancy made another very good point, namely that `COUNTIF` can be used instead of `SEARCH`. This leads to a non-array formula solution and should dominate my original formula, performance-wise.

Here is Doug's formula:

```
FINDIST_COUNTIF = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("COUNTIF(" _
        & ActiveSheet.Cells.Address & "," & Chr(34) & "*"  _ 
          & stringToFind & "*" & Chr(34) & ")")
```

In fact, Doug's point implies that no `Evaluate()` is necessary. We can call `Countif` from the `WorksheetFunction` object. Therefore, if the goal is to call this function from a spreadsheet, there is no need to use `Evaluate()` or to wrap it up in a `UDF` - it is a typical `COUNTIF` application with wildcards.

Results:

```
  Read from range:           247,495 ms (~ 4 mins 7 secs)
  Application.Evaluate:        3,261 ms (~ 3.2 secs)
  Variant Array:               1,706 ms (~ 1.7 secs)
  ActiveSheet.Evaluate:        1,257 ms (~ 1.3 secs)
  ActiveSheet.Evaluate (DG):     602 ms (~ 0.6 secs)
  WorksheetFunction.CountIf (DG):550 ms (~ 0.55 secs)
```

It appears that `Application.Evaluate` is about 75 times faster compared to using `Range.Find()`(?!) Also, the original code (with `Integer` changed to `Long`) runs in ~8 seconds.

Also, it seems that `Activesheet.Evaluate` is actually faster than the `Variant` array in this particular case. The difference between calling `CountIf` as a `WorksheetFunction` method vs `Evaluate`ing it seems quite small.

**CAVEAT**: the frequency by which `stringToFind` is found within the `UsedRange` might affect the relative performance of the several methods. I ran the `Activesheet.Evaluate` and `Variant Array` methods with the above range `(A1:AA100000)` but with only the ten first cells having the matching string.

Results (average of 6 runs, variance pretty much minimal):

```
  Activesheet.Evaluate:        920 ms (~  1. sec)
  Variant Array:               1654 ms (~ 1.7 secs)
```

This is interesting - it seems that `ActiveSheet.Evaluate` in this case has a slightly better performance than variant arrays (unless I have done something horrible in the looping code, in which case please let me know). Also, the `Variant` method's performance is actually.. invariant with respect to the string's frequency.

runs were made on `EXCEL 2010` under `Win7`.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Tony Dallimore's advice of using Find and also changing your return type to Long.

MSDN article: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
Function FINDIST(stringToFind) As Long
Dim counter As Long: counter = 0
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set c = .Find(stringToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, , LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            counter = counter + 1
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

FINDIST = counter

End Function
```

Find is generally quicker than a coded equivalent but I've not speed tested against anything else and will be interested to here if it is quick or slow.