# Application.Evaluate vs. Activesheet.Evaluate

Tags: excel, vba

I was reading this thread
[A custom find function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338296/a-custom-find-function/24340907#24340907)
and this was stated

`Interesting result. Note that Evaluate is same as Application.Evaluate and takes roughly twice as long as Activesheet.Evaluate –  chris neilsen`

Should one always use `Activesheet.Evaluate` in place of `Application.Evaluate`?

Thanks

Comment: That comment is based on [this post by Charles Williams](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you should, but it looks like you can. For example these all work:

```
Activesheet.Evaluate("2")

Activesheet.Evaluate("Sheet1!A1+Sheet2!A1")

Activesheet.Evaluate("SUM([Book1]Sheet1!A1,[Book1]Sheet2!A1,[Book2]Sheet1!A1,[Book2]Sheet2!A1)")
```

The first case is worksheet-agnostic, and it returns the correct result in the Immediate window.

The second refers to two sheets and also returns the correct result. As does the third, which refers to two different workbooks.

The obvious caveat is to always fully qualify any worksheet or workbook references.

Comment: please see link in comment on OP for origin of my comment

Comment: @chrisneilsen, I had read that post following the link in the post that prompted this question. Can you clarify this comment?

Comment: Doug, Thank you for the comments

Comment: My main point was the difference in performance described in the post.  This is confirmed by tests I ran based on the A to the other SO post.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, and that therefore you should use `ActiveSheet.Evaluate`? Is that what you're saying? It seems like a reasonable answer to the question, and I'll certainly try to remember to do so. BTW, did you see my answer to that question, folded into Ioannis's answer?

Comment: @DougGlancy based on Charles' research it would seem so (but `Worksheet.Evaluate` not necessarily `ActiveSheet`).  Yes, seen the update (now).  Optimising the formula `Evaluate` runs has a big impact, well done.